# How to implement 'SomeAsyncWorker()' from Bottle Asynchronous Primer?

Tags: python, asynchronous, bottle, gevent

I have a bunch of long running scripts which do some number crunching and as they run write output to the console via print I want to invoke these scripts from a browser, and display the progress in the browser as they run. I'm currently playing with bottle and am working through this primer http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html# which is rather neat.

I'd like to try Event Callbacks http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html#event-callbacks as this seems to exactly match my problem, the script would run as an AsyncWorker (ideally managed by some message queue to limit the number running at any one instance) and periodically write back it's state. But I cannot figure out what SomeAsyncWorker() is - is it a tornado class or a gevent class I have to implement or something else?

```
@route('/fetch')
def fetch():
    body = gevent.queue.Queue()
    worker = SomeAsyncWorker()
    worker.on_data(body.put)
    worker.on_finish(lambda: body.put(StopIteration))
    worker.start()
    return body
```

Comment: I am also looking for it, but could not find. Did you manage to get it done?

Comment: No sorry I never figure it out and moved on to other alternatives (am not currently using Python so I'm not really even sure what I did in the end)

Comment: Why do I keep getting down votes on this question? Seems to be a reasonable question and there's not been a specific answer, only alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I've found one way of doing this using gevent.queue here http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/jul/31/gevent-long-polling-you/ which shouldn't be hard to adapt to work with bottle

```
# wsgi_longpolling/better_responses.py
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import datetime
import time
from gevent import Greenlet
from gevent import pywsgi
from gevent import queue


def current_time(body):
    current = start = datetime.datetime.now()
    end = start + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)

    while current < end:
        current = datetime.datetime.now()
        body.put('<div>%s</div>' % current.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(1)

    body.put('</body></html>')
    body.put(StopIteration)


def handle(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    body = queue.Queue()
    body.put(' ' * 1000)
    body.put("<html><body><h1>Current Time:</h1>")
    g = Greenlet.spawn(current_time, body)
    return body


server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 1234), handle)
print "Serving on http://127.0.0.1:1234..."
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

(Not exactly an answer to your question, but here's another tack you could take.)

I've cobbled together a very simple [multi-threaded WSGI server](http://ronrothman.com/public/leftbraned/mtwsgi-a-multithreaded-python-wsgi-implementation/) that fits nicely under bottle.  Here's an example:

```
import bottle
import time
from mtbottle import MTServer

app = bottle.Bottle()

@app.route('/')
def foo():
    time.sleep(2)
    return 'hello, world!\n'

app.run(server=MTServer, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, thread_count=3)

# app is nonblocking; it will handle up to 3 requests concurrently.
# A 4th concurrent request will block until one of the first 3 completed.
```

**https://github.com/RonRothman/mtwsgi**

One down side is that *all* endpoints on that port will be asynchronous; in contrast, the gevent method (I think) gives you more control over which methods are asynchronous and which are synchronous.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. I'm happy to look at any options, so far I've tried socket.io etc but they all seem overly complex for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: While it's not really an async solution, it served to get me moving on.

Comment: @Lars: I disagree; in any case, to the extent that it's not exactly answer, I've already added an acknowledgement. Merely stating "not an answer" does not help anyone; I welcome your constructive edits. Thanks.